# C++ Function Gives "Not all Control Paths Return A Value" Error

Tags: c++

I am working on a function called add(BigDecimals c) which keeps getting an error that not all control paths are returning a value:

```
BigDecimal BigDecimal::add(BigDecimal c)
{
    string fFirst = to_string(this->fraction()); //fraction part of the first number
    string fSecond = to_string(c.fraction()); //fraction part of the second number

    if (fFirst.length() < fSecond.length()) //fraction part of first/second number
    {
        string str(this->toString()); //convert fraction to string
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < fFirst.length() - fSecond.length(); i++) //difference between first and second
        {
            str += "0"; //pad in the 0's
        }
        this->equals(str); //call the equals function
    }

    if (fSecond.length() < fFirst.length()) //flip numbers around, second < first
    {
        string str(this->toString()); //convert fraction to string
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < fSecond.length() - fFirst.length(); i++)  //difference between second and first
        {
            str += "0"; //pad in the 0's
        }
        this->equals(str); //call the equals function
    }

    for (unsigned int i = fSecond.length(); i > 0; i++)
    {
        int carryFlag = 0; //carry flag set to 0
        int sum = carryFlag + stoi(this->at(i).toString()) + stoi(c.at(i).toString());
        if (sum >= 10) //greater than 10
        {
            carryFlag = 1;
            sum = sum % 10;
        }

        else //less than 10
        {
            carryFlag = 0; //set carry flag to 0
        }
        return BigDecimal(to_string(sum)); //this is the only thing I want to
                                           //return
    }
    //It wants to return something here, but I am not sure what.


}
```

I have tried to fix this by replacing if statements with else statements, but nothing really works. I have no idea how to fix this error, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Note that if the last loop doesn't enter, nothing will be returned.

Comment: Your logic is flawed. The `for` loop will always return on the first iteration, so the loop doesn't do much more than an `if` would. Edit : It seems like you may intend for `sum` to be declared outside the loop and to simply move the `return` to after the loop.

Comment: Unless the `equals` function does something completely counterintuitive, `this->equals(str)` (which could be written `equals(str)` is pointless. What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Isn't `stoi(this->at(i).toString())` the same as `this->at(i)`?

Comment: Well if I put sum outside the for loop and return outside the for loop, it gives me an error that sum is not initialized. Is there any way I can initialize sum to something that would not matter, or do I need to fix this another way?

Comment: If to_string returns empty strings for both, control will reach the end there.  From the other comments, it looks like there are other problems with the algorithm, though, and that last loop certainly doesn't look right (return on first iteration).

Comment: for (unsigned int i = fSecond.length(); i > 0; i++) <-- start with one past the last index, and increment while i > 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is flawed (and the error message and the fact you don't know what to do about it is a good indication of that).

Your code will always return on the first iteration of the loop. Clearly what you want to do is accumulate a digit string one digit at a time, but that's not what the code you've written does.

This is something more like what you want. However I think you have other errors to do with the padding of numbers, so this code isn't going to work, but hopefully will give you some idea.

```
string result = "";
int carryFlag = 0; //carry flag set to 0
for (unsigned int i = fSecond.length(); i > 0; i--)
{
    int sum = carryFlag + stoi(this->at(i).toString()) + stoi(c.at(i).toString());
    if (sum >= 10) //greater than 10
    {
        carryFlag = 1;
        sum = sum % 10;
    }

    else //less than 10
    {
        carryFlag = 0; //set carry flag to 0
    }
    result = to_string(sum) + result;
}
if (carryflag)
    result = "1" + result;
return BigDecimal(result);
```

Notice the return is only after the loop has finished, and a new variable called result accumulates the digit generated each time round the loop.

Also notice the `carryflag` variable has been moved outside of the loop. The whole point of the carry is to hold the carry from one iteration of the loop to the next, so it can't be inside the loop. Also if there is a carry left over after all the digits have been added, you need to add a one digit to the beginning of the result.

Also I've changed `i++` to `i--` in the loop. You are iterating backwards through the strings you are adding so you need `i--`. It's an improvment but as I said before I still think this loop is wrong.

Clearly you understand how to do long addition, but what you haven't mastered yet is how to translate that into code. You have to think very carefully and precisely about what you are asking the computer to do.